# command php artisan dusk, get error: Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I run `php artisan dusk` and get error:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException:

Tests\Browser\HomePageTest::testBasicContentOnPage
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY"}}

Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

/home/vagrant/Code/jobboard/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:287
/home/vagrant/Code/jobboard/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:121
/home/vagrant/Code/jobboard/tests/DuskTestCase.php:33
/home/vagrant/Code/jobboard/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/TestCase.php:209
/home/vagrant/Code/jobboard/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:762
/home/vagrant/Code/jobboard/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/TestCase.php:210
/home/vagrant/Code/jobboard/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/TestCase.php:116
/home/vagrant/Code/jobboard/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/TestCase.php:88
/home/vagrant/Code/jobboard/tests/Browser/HomePageTest.php:21
```

I googled and founded solution: download chromedriver and run manual.

1 .I downloaded and installed chromedriver.

2. Manual run script /usr/local/bin/chromedriver. Terminal display now:

   Starting ChromeDriver 2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5) on port 9515
   Only local connections are allowed.
3. I commented line `static::startChromeDriver();` in DuskCaseTest.php

I am again running test and get same error.

My stack:

- Laravel, 5.5
- ubuntu 16.08
- php 7
- vagrant
- homestead.

How solve this issue? Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, reading [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/82q4an/getting_strange_failures_in_dusk_and_wrong/) and other places, it seems that Dusk is no killing the previous processes of ChromeDriver.

The steps you mention worked for me. Here's my workflow:

1. Download the latest version of ChromeDriver.
2. Make sure there are no ChromeDriver processes running from previous Dusk attempts.
3. Run ChromeDriver manually outside from Dusk.
4. Comment the static::startChromeDriver() line.
5. Make sure that the default port is 9515.
6. Run your tests.

It worked for me on Linux Mint 18.3.

As a curious note, after that and un-commenting the line in Dusk, it worked as expected, but it keeps creating a process per call. I don't like that, so I'll keep with starting manually outside from Dusk.